# Adding subviews to headerview: added to a wrong section

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a tableview with 2 sections

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  switch (section) { 
    case 0: return @"s1"; 
    case 1: return @"s2"; 
  } 
}
```

I wanted to add a label to section 0.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView(nonnull UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
  if (section == 0) {
    for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
      if (subView.tag == 99) {
         [subView removeFromSuperview];
         break;
      }
    }

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 150 - headerView.textLabel.frame.origin.x, headerView.textLabel.frame.origin.y, 150, hederView.textLabel.frame.size.height)];

    label.text = @"test";
    label.tag = 99;
    [headerView addSubview:label];
  }
}
```

It works ok for initial display.

Then I use presentViewController to pop up a camera Image Picker, but whenever I dismiss the image picker, and return back to the current view, the "test" label will be in both seciton 0 and section 1.

Meaning that there will be 2 "test" in both two sections.

If I use

```
if (section == 1) {
  for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
    if (subView.tag == 99) {
      [subView removeFromSuperview];
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This will remove the extra "test" from section 1.

Is there any possible reasons for that? I tried to debug and cannot see anything useful on why this happens, because after the if (section == 0) block finished running, it will go into assembly mode, if I continue running from the break, section 1 will show up "test", and I don't know where it comes from.

I am not asking for solution (I had one, just to remove the tag 99 label from section 1), I am asking for reason and any place that I did wrong.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: because your headers are reused, you should implement somewhere method with `prepareToReuse` logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you `instantiate` the `UITableViewController` class, the `TableView` is reloaded with two different views for both your sections. When you return to the same `UITableViewController` a new instance is not instantiated. But probably you have a `reloadData()` call in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. Now the `TableView` is reloaded with the previous `views` reused for your `Headers`. The view1 for section 1 in previous instantiation becomes the view for section 0 now.(at this point you add the `UILabel` as `subView` for this view1) The view0 of previous instantiation becomes the view for section 1 now.(it already has label as `subView` from previous instantiation). Thus when you return to this same `TableViewController` and since it is not instantiated again, both the views for header has label as `subView`

You can avoid the `reloadData()` call from view will appear and it looks fine or follow the best practice of `overriding` the method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) ->     UIView?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add header in following way..

add two function

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

```
            return 40.0
    }



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let vw_header : UIView = UIView()
    vw_header.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, 40)
    vw_header.backgroundColor = Validation.getColorByRGB(227, G: 227, B: 227)
    vw_header.layer.borderWidth = 1
    vw_header.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor


    let txtHeaderText : UILabel = UILabel()
    txtHeaderText.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, 40)
    txtHeaderText.textColor = appTextPurpleColor
    txtHeaderText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    txtHeaderText.text = “Simple Header”

    vw_header.addSubview(txtHeaderText)

    return vw_header
}
```

Now u can customize the header section view according ur requirement